# footnote in \author reports the color as text

Tags: color, author

Latex report the color of footnote as a text next to the footnote symbol. Do you have any guess how I can remove this 'red' from the symbol of author?

Best regards,
N.

`{\vspace{-2.0cm}My Title}`
`\author[1,2]{Author one \footnote{Corresponding author: XXX}}`
`\author[1,2]{Author two}`
`\affil[1]{Affiliation one} \affil[2]{Affiliation two}`

[image]

Comment: show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: As usual, please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), as this problem likely comes from somewhere else in your document.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time on the forum. Should I copy paste my preamble? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @n61 Just follow the link I provided, it explains what a MWE is. Also, just those three words tell you almost everything: the Example should be Minimal (as short as possible) and Working (compilable).